# Окно поверх сцены

Tags: unity3d

Как добавить подобное окно поверх, оставляя сцену позади обновляемой. Пересмотрел кучу гайдов по созданию кликеров, но так и не нашел что-либо подобного, там выполняли просто переход на другую сцену.
Желательно, объяснить как последнему идиоту(начинающему), ну или скинуть видео, если такое есть. Спасибо.

[image]

Comment: Это называется UI, туториалов в интернете миллион.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте кнопку, нацепите на неё этот скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    private bool active;
    public void Activate(){
        active = !active;
        menu.SetActive(active);
    }
}
```

В поле OnClick перетащите объект кнопки и выберите метод activate().